# How to call proper assignment operator of custom class inside std::variant

Tags: c++, std

I have the following class:

```
class StackStringHolder
{
public:
    StackStringHolder& operator=(const std::string& str)
    {
        str_ = str;
        return *this;
    }
    StackStringHolder& operator=(std::string&& str)
    {
        str_ = std::move(str);
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& get() const { return str_; }

private:
    std::string str_;
};
```

And I want to use it in the `std::variant` the following way:

```
int main() {
    std::variant<int, StackStringHolder> var;
    var = 5;
    std::string str = "Hello";
    var = str; // error
    var = std::move(str); // error
}
```

However compiler (MSVS2022) says:

> error C2679: binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand
> operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Update, I'm sure my pieces of code enough, but as I'm asked for, here is the complete example:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class StackStringHolder
{
public:
    StackStringHolder& operator=(const std::string& str)
    {
        str_ = str;
        return *this;
    }
    StackStringHolder& operator=(std::string&& str)
    {
        str_ = std::move(str);
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string& get() const { return str_; }

private:
    std::string str_;
};

int main() {
    std::variant<int, StackStringHolder> var;
    var = 5;
    std::string str = "Hello";
    var = str; // error
    var = std::move(str); // error

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Cause of the Problem:**

Your `var` can hold either an `int` or a `StackStringHolder`, so you cannot trivially assign it with a `std::string`.

**Solution:**

You can however add a [**converting constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) to your class `StackStringHolder` which accepts a `std::string`.
Then it can be used to convert `str` to `StackStringHolder` and assign it to `var`.

Your **converting constructor** should look something like:

```
StackStringHolder(std::string const& str)
    : str_(str)  {}
```

**Now you can use:**

```
var = str;
var = std::move(str);
```

Comment: That would be the better option anyway, as it doesn't make sense to first construct a default StackStringHolder and then assign a string to it.